# How can I make Kubernetes mount the entire volume, and grow as it grows?

Tags: kubernetes

I have an NFS server with 30GB, I mount it like so, and inside of the pod, I see only 10gb.

```
  volumes:
  - name: server-nfs-storage
    nfs: 
        server: --.--.--.--
        path: "/"
```

I want to avoid creating PVC, because PVC can't be changed in current release, I won't be able to change the size of the volume.

To put in a more general form: 
How can I make Kubernetes mount the entire volume, and grow as it grows?

Using Kubernetes 1.9

Comment: What release of Kubernetes are you using? Could you share more information about your NFS server? Is it a pod inside the cluster or standalone server? If it's a pod, please share its YAML configuration. If it's a server outside the cluster please share, its configuration file (at least most crucial part). That helps me to reproduce the issue and find the solution suitable for you.

Comment: I didn't specify about NFS because it's not there yet. Could be both inside, or outside doesn't matter.